# DELETING messages in discord.py Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i wrote a bot using Python 3.6 IDLE and i want to add a `purge` command but i don't know how to add it. Can some of you people help me with giving any examples or suggestion i will be pleased thanks.

Comment: There's a [`Client.delete_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_message) coroutine. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Which messages would be deleted after calling your `purge` command?  All the messages in that channel, or all the messages on that server, all the messages from a specific user?

Answer (score 1):

```python
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount):
    await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=amount)
```

pretty sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(pass_context = True, aliases=['Clear'])
async def clear(ctx, number):
    mgs = [] #Empty list to put all the messages in the log
    number = int(number) #Converting the amount of messages to delete to an 
    #integer(number)
    async for x in ctx.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number):
        mgs.append(x)
    await ctx.delete_messages(mgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this command myself and I am sharing it with you.

First I would add the code and then explain.

#### Code:

```
@MyBot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, limit):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    limit = int(limit)
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    cofirmdelete_embed = discord.Embed(title='Delete Successfull!', description=f'Deleted {len(deleted)} messages in #{ctx.channel}', color=0x4fff4d)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=cofirmdelete_embed, delete_after=4.0)
```

#### Explanation:

- `@command.has_permissions(administrator=True)` is added so that this command can be used by administrators only. You can use any discord permissions here and set them to `True` or `False` as per your wish. Eg: `manage_messages=True`
- In `async def clear(ctx, limit)`, `limit` is the amount of messages that you want to delete.
- `ctx.message.delete()` deletes the command that you enter to clear. That is, when you give the bot command: `!clear` it would first delete this command and then execute the latter.
- `deleted` is the variable that I use to get the number of messages that were deleted.
- `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)`. Here, `purge` is a coroutine in the discord.py library. It deleted the messages with the limit that was added by the user.
- In the `confirmdelete_embed`, I have added a description where I have added `len(delete)`. This counts the number of deleted messages and then add it to the embed.

---

This was all that I could explain. I am still here if something comes up or you have any doubt. Feel free to ask me.